# Trick Windows 7 into Thinking It Is Installed on a Tablet PC

Tags: windows, microsoft-onenote, windows-tabletpc, tablet-pc

Is there a way to make Windows 7 think it is installed on a tablet pc? (Not like an iPad but a convertible laptop)

The reason is, I'm having trouble with OneNote and Wacom Cintiq the handwriting is pretty awful in OneNote, But if I use my Lenovo X60T (a convertible laptop) the handwriting is beautiful.

I'm sure it is not an issue on the Cintiq's end because in MyPaint or Photoshop the lines are smooth. Only in OneNote is the pen jagged.

There is a [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818230) that says that "On a Tablet PC, you can capture ink in OneNote with the Tablet pen ... can capture your ink at over 130 samples per second."

BUT

"When you are not on a Tablet PC, OneNote no longer has access to the handwriting recognition engines of the Tablet PC ...  the sample rate will be the lower 40 samples per second"

So, I'm wondering if it is possible to change a registry setting or whatever to make Win7 think it is on a TabletPC, or otherwise get the higher sample rate.

Tested systems:

Core i5
6GBs RAM
1GB Graphic card (Discreet not integrated)

On an old P4 3Ghz with 2 GBs of RAM and the writing is no better OR NO WORSE.

only on my tablet PC (The Lenovo X60) is the pen smooth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

No need to to trick Windows 7. All you have to do is turn on Tablet PC components.

Locate the "Turn Windows Features On or Off" control panel and turn on "Tablet PC Components".
This will add several components to your system, including the Tablet Input Panel which will get you what you need.

Comment: But it's already enabled. I think it got enabled when I installed the Cintiq's drivers. It seems like even though this is enabled, Windows (or OneNote) doesn't know it. Or something.